# Using a flag number within unsigned integers

Tags: c++, c

Many times people will combine a boolean check by just re-using an `int` variable they already have and checking for `-1` if something exists or not.

However, what if someone wants to use unsigned integers but still wants to use this method and also where `0` actually has a different meaning besides existance.

Is there a way to have a data range be -1 to 4,294,967,294?

The obvious choice here is to just use a `bool` that detects what you are after but it is my understanding that a `bool` is a byte, and can really add to the storage size if you have an array of structs. This is why I wondered if there was a way to get the most useful numbers you can (postivies) all while leaving just one number to act as a flag.

Infact, if it is possible to do something like shifting the data range of a data type, it would seem like shifting it to something like -10 to 4,294,967,285 would allow you to have 10 boolean flags at no additional cost (bits).

The obvious hacky method here is just to add whatever number to what your storing and remember to account for it later on, but I wanted to keep it a bit more readable (I guess if thats the case I shouldnt even be using -1, but meh).

Comment: How about using `uint32_t`, use the range 0 to 4,294,967,294 and then `4,294,967,295` is the flag.  What ever the flag is (-1, 4,294,967,295 or whatever) it should be expressible as a macro or constant.  `if (i == SpecialFlag)  DoDifferentCode();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to pick a value which can not exist in your interpretation of the variable and to use it to indicate an exception or error value, why not to simply do it? You can take such a value, define it as a macro and use it. For example if you are sure that your variable never reaches the max limit, put:

```
#define MY_FUN_ERROR_VALUE (UINT_MAX)
```

then you can use it as:

```
unsigned r = my_function_maybe_returning_error();
if (r == MY_FUN_ERROR_VALUE) {handle error}
```

you shall also ensure that `my_function_maybe_returning_error` does not return MY_FUN_ERROR_VALUE in normal conditions when actually no error happens. For this you may use an `assert`:

```
unsigned my_function_maybe_returning_error() {
    ...
    // branch going to return normal (not error) value r
    assert(r != MY_FUN_ERROR_VALUE);
    return(r);
}
```

I do not see anything wrong on this.

Answer (score 0):

You just asked how to use a value that can be 0 or something greater than 0 to hold the three states: whatever 0 means, something greater than 0, and does not exist. So no, (by the pigeonhole principle I guess) it's not possible.

Nor should it be. Overloading a variable is bad practice unless you're down to your last 3 bytes left of RAM, which you almost certainly aren't. So yes, please use another variable with a correct name and clear purpose.

Comment: I agree with you that it is bad practice. It was more of a question/curiousity if there was a way to alias a datatype or define your own with a custom range. The application I was considering might be where every single little byte counts such as 1,000,000,000 objects in which that 1 byte matters a lot.